# Parallelize requests call with asyncio in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio

I'm trying to create an interface to an API, and I want to have the option to easily run the requests sync or asynchronously, and I came up with the following code.

```py
import asyncio
import requests

def async_run(coro_list):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = [loop.run_in_executor(None, asyncio.run, coro) for coro in coro_list]
    result = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*futures))
    return result

def sync_get(url):
    return requests.get(url)

async def async_get(url):
    return sync_get(url)

coro_list = [async_get("https://google.com"), async_get("https://google.com")]
responses = async_run(coro_list)
print(responses)
```

For me it's very intuitive to either call `sync_get` or create a list of `async_get` and call `async_run`, and requires no knowledge of async Python to understand how it works.

The only problem is that `loop.run_in_executor(None, asyncio.run, coro)` doesn't sound too optimal, and I couldn't find anyone else running this code on Github. So I'm wondering, is there a simpler way to accomplish the objective of abstracting these `threading` and `asyncio` concepts in some similar way, or is this code already optimal?

Comment: Your goal isn’t clear. Your code isn’t asynchronous (in the asyncio sense) because you are using requests. If you want to use threads and requests, why not just use concurrent.futures?

Comment: @dirn my goal is to abstract `asyncio` concepts behind this API interface class, and have no code duplication between synchronous and asynchronous functions, such as using `requests` for one, and `aiohttp` for the other.
To call the api synchronously, I do`sync_get(url)`, to do it async, I do `async_run([async_get(url), async_post(url2), ...])`.
This is the code I came up with based on these requirements, I'm just not happy with the `async_run()` function code, which I think could be improved, but I'm trying to learn more about it. I'll look into `concurrent.futures`, thanks!

Comment: @dirn using threads wouldn't allow me to have the `async_get()` as a coroutine, right? Then I wouldn't be able to have this `async_run()` syntax I'm after.
Well, I imagine my code will work fine, I'll try to figure out what the downside of doing `[loop.run_in_executor(None, asyncio.run, coro) for coro in coro_list]` is, but if it's only few extra CPU power needed, I might stick to it.

Comment: But `async_get` isn’t really asynchronous. It calls and blocks on `sync_get`  Unless you actually plan on using an asyncio-aware way to make requests, I don’t see the value in `async_get`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `asyncio.run()` is usually used as the main entry to run async code from sync code.
2. `loop.run_in_executor(None, asyncio.run, coro)` cause an event loop created in executor threads to run `coro` in `coro_list`. Why not directly run `sync_get` in executor threads?

```py
import asyncio
import requests

def async_run(url_list):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = [loop.run_in_executor(None, sync_get, url) for url in url_list]
    result = await asyncio.gather(*futures)
    return result

def sync_get(url):
    return requests.get(url)

# 
# async def async_get(url):
#     return sync_get(url)

url_list = ["https://google.com", "https://google.com"]

responses = asyncio.run(async_run(url_list))
print(responses)
```

3. There are async libaries, eg. `aiohttp` and `httpx`, to accomplish similar work.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I chose not to cover completely `asyncio` under my interface.

Still with the goal of having not having to manage 2 "requests" functions, I made the API async first, and run the synchronous one with `asyncio` and I ended up with something like this.

```
def sync_request():
  return asyncio.run(async_request(...))

async def async_request():
  return await aiohttp.request(...) # pseudo code
```